# Toolbar not showing app name and back button

Tags: java, android, xml

So because of my problems with toolbar shadow, which I posted here earlier, I came up with idea how to remove it. Now there's no shadow at least, but there's no activity name or back button. See image below

[image]

Here's the content.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="0dp"

    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="hr.app.liftme.liftmehr.Vjezbe"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_vjezbe">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:text="Vježbe"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <include
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"
            >

        </include>





        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            app:tabMode="scrollable"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager

            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"
            android:background="#ffffff">

        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>





    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and here's the toolbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/toolBar"

    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

java file

```
package hr.app.liftme.liftmehr;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;

public class Vjezbe extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_vjezbe);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar == null){


        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Vježbe");
            getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
    }


        tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
        viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
//here are the fragments, not going to copy all of that
```

As you can see I tried something with if statement in java file, but that didn't work.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

**`if (toolbar == null)`**

**Solutions**

Use `!null` checking instead of `null`

```
 if (toolbar != null){

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Vježbe");
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
    }
```

**Edit**

```
 // toolbar
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
        //Your code
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Vježbe");
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
    }
```

**Worked**

By adding `android:elevation="0dp"` .

Comment: Did that, but still no title and back button

Comment: `toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("TITLE");

        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.your_back_icon);`

Comment: @DaxHR For test case use above

Comment: Thank you for your time. I solved the problem by removing the toolbar and setting elevation to 0 in activity.xml, not in content.xml as I tryed before

Comment: yes, I constantly tried to put that line in content.xml, but it obviously should be put in activity.xml

Answer (score 1):

remove 
`if(toolbar==null)` beacuse this condition is true only if **toolbar** is null

and make it

```
 if (toolbar != null){
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Vježbe");
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
    }
```

Comment: Did that, but still no title and back button

Answer (score 1):

Just Add this code to you onCreate event like this:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.example_activity);//set view

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);// initial your tool bar 
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);//set tool bar
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);//allow back button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);//Show back arrow
        getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.yourlogo);//set logo
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);//enable log

}
```